# What is the difference between the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Tags: android

What is the difference between the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes
in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

As in the doc :

> android:versionCode — An integer value that represents the version of
>   the application code, relative to other versions. The value is an
>   integer so that other applications can programmatically evaluate it,
>   for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set
>   the value to any integer you want, however you should make sure that
>   each successive release of your application uses a greater value. The
>   system does not enforce this behavior, but increasing the value with
>   successive releases is normative. Typically, you would release the
>   first version of your application with versionCode set to 1, then
>   monotonically increase the value with each release, regardless whether
>   the release constitutes a major or minor release. This means that the
>   android:versionCode value does not necessarily have a strong
>   resemblance to the application release version that is visible to the
>   user (see android:versionName, below). Applications and publishing
>   services should not display this version value to users.
>
> android:versionName — A string value that represents the release
>   version of the application code, as it should be shown to users. The
>   value is a string so that you can describe the application version as
>   a .. string, or as any other type of absolute or
>   relative version identifier. As with android:versionCode, the system
>   does not use this value for any internal purpose, other than to enable
>   applications to display it to users. Publishing services may also
>   extract the android:versionName value for display to users.

source : http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html#appversioning